# how to pass values to a web view which is loading a react native app

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

i am new to react native and very familiar to iOS with swift language.My requirement is in an iOS existing app there will be a web view which is loading a react native app ,here i want to use some values of iOS app in react native.

for example , in iOS app there will be an authorization code ,this auth code i want to use in react native app which is loading in UIWebview.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
        loadReactNativeApp()
    
        }
    

    func loadReactNativeApp(){
            let link = "https://staging.abcdefg.com:1442/appname_web/"
    
                let finalUrl:URL!
             finalUrl = URL(string: link)
     
                let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: finalUrl!)
    
                webview.load(urlRequest)
               
            }
```

I don't have idea how could we pass the values to react native app.Can any one help me to solve my problem would be great.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `injectedJavaScript` prop from `WebView`.

Eg:
First declare a `jsCode` variable:

```
const amount = 2
const jscode = `
  if (document.getElementById('txtAmount') == null) {
      // field not existing, deal with the error
    } else {
      document.getElementById('txtAmount').value = '${amount}';
    }
`
```

Please notice the " ` " character. Used to put variables in strings.

Then use it like so:

```
<WebViewBridge
  injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
```

Comment: actually WebViews will be in iOS native app.and we are passing a staging url to that WebViews along with some values like auth token.